# iDevice app orientation before and after interstitial ads

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Hi I have an app (SpriteKit) that I have set it to only portrait under Target > General > Deployment Info. Also in my info.plist, I have `supported interface orientations` set to `Portrait (bottom home button)` and `supported interface orientations (iPad)` set to `Portrait (bottom home button)` and `Portrait (top home button)`. This works for most part, however when an interstitial ad is shown, and the device is rotated to landscape mode, the ad rotates too. When the ad is closed, the app stays in landscape mode, and it is not displayed right (i.e. zoomed in so that the width of the app fits the width of the screen and top and bottom is cut off).

I played with the settings a little and found that setting this code makes it work fine, for now at least. I was just wondering if this is the right way to do it? Will there be an issue during the official app review? What are your suggestions? Any comments?

```
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .Portrait  // used to be return .AllButUpsideDown, changed this and everything works for now

    } else {
        return .Portrait  // used to be return .All
    }
}
```

Comment: what ad service are you using?  Also before anybody else pesters you with this, iAd will end in June, and they are not taking any new apps, so if you are using iAd, first switch to another ad service, then see if you get the same problem

Comment: I am using iAds as my primary and if iAds fail to load AdMob will take over. I just need to know if there is anything wrong with including the code above to rectify my problem.

Comment: already told you,  if you are including iAd, your app will not pass review.  Do you get the problem with admob?  will the above code not pass,  of course it will pass,  apple doesn't actually get your source code.  Since Admob is not a part of Apple though, you need to make sure that it doesn't crash, because a crash will get it sent back

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood what you said. Without the above code, the problem does not exists with adMob, because tapping on the adMob interstitial ad opens Safari instead. Also I am not getting any crashes.

Comment: ok, then you have your answer lol

Comment: Thanks haha. Though the iAds shutting down issue is a little confusing. i.e see [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363271/submission-of-new-app-with-iads) Which of it is the true answer?(this might need a new qeustion)

Comment: The site actually says they are not accepting new apps,  the iAD framework may end up changing, but could still exist,  but if you cant get the iAD id when you go through the app creation process, then your app won't show ads, and it will fail review regardless

Comment: Apple does call consider all of iAD as the iAd app network,  see https://developer.apple.com/iad/monetize/

Comment: Looks like they are shutting down for good [Reddit Discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/4624ud/is_iad_really_closing_down/). So like you said, as long as my apps arent showing any iAds the app wont get rejected (assuming everything else goes well)?  even if I have remnants of iAd code left behind

Comment: Yeah the code itself wont hurt it,  iAd itself may not go away, it may end up like ad mob,  you get a list of providers, and attach it to the network.  Then knowing apple, all apps must be run thru iAd,  making the providers pay a fee to run thru the iAd API